# Why do I get the warning: "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given"?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, parameters

I have the following code:

```
$result=$db->query("SELECT * FROM gwub WHERE gwubStatus > 0") or die(mysqli_error($db));

if($result->num_rows>0) 
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

The query is running and doing what it requires on the database but I am still getting the following warning:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   string given

I am getting no mysqli errors and if i run command direct on database it works fine. There is only one result if that makes any difference?

Comment: Run this separately `SELECT * FROM gwub WHERE gwubStatus > 0`

Comment: I have ran that in phpmyadmin and get 1 result and no errors which is correct

Comment: `var_dump($result)` after `->query`, what value is in it?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Is there any other code between the if statement and the while loop?

Comment: No, exactly as written above, have thousands of pages of code and most contain queries but only this one throwing an error?

Comment: Can you share more of that code? Is it possible that you modify `$result` within the `while` loop?

Comment: Is there an assignment to `$result` inside the loop?

Comment: No the only references to $result are in original code above, nothing else on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet anything you have an assignment to `$result` inside your loop, e.g. something like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result = $row['some_column'];
}
```

After that assignment, `$result` no longer contains the result of the query, it contains that column, which is a string. The next iteration of the loop tries to use that string when it calls `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`, and this fails.

Solution: use a different variable inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, just found this within loop, so simple: $result = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: Edit the question and show the code, so we can reopen the question.

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

`while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result->result_array())) {`

this will give the array of the result.

Comment: There is no `result_array()` method in `mysqli_result`. That's a CodeIgniter method.